# Explode pandas dataframe column values to separate rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have following pandas dataframe:

```
id          term            code
2445 | 2716 abcd | efgh     2345
1287        hgtz            6567
```

I would like to explode `id` and `term` column. How can I explode multiple columns to keep the values across the columns `id`, `term` and `code` together.

The expected output is:

```
id          term            code
2445        abcd            2345
2716        efgh            2345
1287        hgtz            6567
```

I have tried so far is:
`df.assign(id=df['id'].str.split(' | ')).explode('id')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're in the right way, you just need some help from [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with a *listcomp* :

```
out = (
        pd.concat([df[col].str.split("\s*\|\s*")
                          .explode() for col in ["id", "term"]], axis=1)
             .join(df["code"])
      )
```

Output :
​
print(out)

```
     id  term  code
0  2445  abcd  2345
0  2716  efgh  2345
1  1287  hgtz  6567
```

Comment: You can remove `replace` and use a regex with `split`: `str.split(r'\s*\|\s*')`. Especially if the term column contains multiple words for one term.

Comment: This make the code shorter/better. Thanks for the trick, Corralien ;)

Answer (score 3):

here is a way using `.str.split()` and `explode()` which can accept multiple columns

```
(df[['id','term']].stack()
.str.split(' | ',regex=False)
.unstack()
.explode(['id','term'])
.join(df[['code']]))
```

Output:

```
     id  term  code
0  2445  abcd  2345
0  2716  efgh  2345
1  1287  hgtz  6567
```